# How can i change my Telerik CartesianGrid size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telerik

[This](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/p_telerik_wincontrols_ui_uichartelement_size.html) is the property i want to change

This is what i have try:

```
CartesianGrid cartesianGrid = area.GetGrid<CartesianGrid>();
cartesianGrid.Size = 5;
```

And this is my error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Drawing.Size'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation you linked clearly states, the `Size` property is expecting an object of type [`System.Drawing.Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You are giving it an integer.

Try making a `Size` object and setting it to that instead. Something like:

```
cartesianGrid.Size = new Size(5,5);
```